# Cumulative min on earlier versions of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am using **PostgreSQL 8.2**, which is main reason why I'm asking this question. I want to get in this version of PostgreSQL a column (let name it C) with cumulative minimum for some other preordered column (let name it B). So on n-th row of column C should be minimum of values of B in rows 1 to n for some ordering.

In example below column A gives order and column C contains cumulative minimum for column B in that order:

```
A   B     C
------------
1   5     5     
2   4     4  
3   6     4  
4   5     4  
5   3     3
6   1     1
```

Probably easiest way to explain what I want is what, in later versions, next query does:

```
SELECT A , B, min (B)  OVER(ORDER BY A) C FROM T;
```

But version 8.2, of course, don't have window functions.

I've written some plpgsql functions that do this on arrays. But to use this I have to use **array_agg** aggregate function that I again wrote myself (there no built in array_agg in that version). This approach isn't very efficient and while it worked well on smaller tables it becoming almost unusable now that I need to use it on bigger ones.

So I would be very grateful for any suggestions of alternative, more efficient solutions of this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use this simple subselect:

```
SELECT a, b, (SELECT min(b) FROM t t1 WHERE t1.a <= t.a) AS c
FROM   t
ORDER  BY a;
```

But I doubt it will be faster for big tables than a plpgsql function. Maybe you can show us your function. There might be room for improvement there.

For this to be fast you should have a multi-column index like:

```
CREATE INDEX t_a_b_idx ON t (a,b);
```

But really, you should upgrade your to a more recent version of PostgreSQL. Version 8.2 has reached end of life last year. No more security updates. And so many missing features ...